# Length of the inner-most plain-text argument (token sequence) in a nested macro expression (via expl3)

Tags: expl3, latex3

I would like to determine the length of the original token sequence passed to the inner-most macro as in

```
\compl{\indexset{J}}
```

where

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\indexset}{m}{\mathsf{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\compl}{m}{{#1}^{\complement}}
```

which results in a serif J with an appropriate C in superscript, within a math context.

Now I want to get the integer length of the argument `J` passed to `\indexset` and not the length of the expansion which would be `\mathsf{J}`. The purpose is to decide whether to use parentheses and how to format them.

I imagine I could simply extract the last item. Would

```
\tl_head:n {\tl_reverse:n {#1}}
```

or

```
\tl_item:nn {#1} {\tl_count:n {#1}}
```

do? In this case, however, I suppose, expressions like `\mx{1,2,3}'` (with a terminating apostrophe, akin MATLAB/Octave syntax and meaning---transpose) would yield the wrong last item.

I still get perplexed about the concept of expansion, which is to say that I haven't properly learned it, which may be the root to the issue I am having.

---

I would like to extend this question as follows.

How do I also properly (canonically?) measure the length of an **inner-most** subscript or superscript expression like `i_{n-k}`, given the restrictions stated above? That is, if the inner-most expression is not a plain-text character sequence but is itself an expression, albeit *not* a macro. I am particularly interested in the specific cases of subscript and superscript.

For example,

```
\compl{\indexset{I}_{n-k}}
```

or

```
\compl{\indexset{I_{n-k}}}
```

in which case I only care for the length of `I`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What about `\compl{A\indexset{J}}`? Without knowing what arguments the macro `\compl` is expected to be called with, it's difficult to provide hints.

Comment: Thanks! Since this is primarily for my personal use (and maybe my research colleagues, at most), it is very unlikely that such a branching (leaf & node) would occur. I may be underestimating the purpose, but at least for now, please assume that every node has at most two neighbors. So, just a pass-through chain.

Comment: Note that `\mathsf{I_{n-k}}` is generally wrong.

Comment: Absolutely, it would, on the other hand, simplify the traversal for the implementor. As a transitory solution, at cost of a simplified implementation I'd be fine with a semantically incorrect notion.

Comment: Just a comment: `\tl_head:n {\tl_reverse:n {#1}}`this would extract `\tl_reverse:n`, which is the first token. What you want is to *expand* first the argument (reversing it), then get the head: `\tl_head:f` or `\tl_head:x` will expand it before getting the “head”.